# Construct ident from string/int in declarative macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a dozen crates all with two functions `part1()` and `part2()`. For each of those, I want to print the return value of both functions. To not repeat myself, I wrote a little macro, so my main crate's `main()` looks like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    macro_rules! print_day {
        ($day:ident) => {
            let day = stringify!($day).replace('d', "");
            println!("Day {day} Part 1: {}", $day::part1());
            println!("Day {day} Part 2: {}", $day::part2());
        };
    }

    print_day!(d01);
    print_day!(d02);
    print_day!(d03);
    // list goes on..
}
```

Is it possible to construct an ident from a string or int in a declarative macro, so I could instead do like below? All I've found is either for proc macros, using additional packages or the other way round.

```rust
fn main() {
    macro_rules! print_day {
        ($day:expr) => {
            let daystr = format!("{:02}", $day);
            let dayident = ???;
            println!("Day {daystr} Part 1: {}", $dayident::part1());
            println!("Day {daystr} Part 2: {}", $dayident::part2());
        };
    }

    for day in 0..=num_days {
        print_day!(day);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use the [`paste`](https://crates.io/crates/paste) crate. There are a few similar ones too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [concat_idents](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html) you can glue identifiers together, but unfortunately it does not (yet?) allow non-identifiers such as numbers.

```rust
#![feature(concat_idents)]

fn m_1() {
    println!("Hi");
}

macro_rules! m {
    ($n:ident) => {
        concat_idents!(m, $n)();
    };
}

fn main() {
    // underscore is needed to make it into an identifier
    m!(_1);
}
```

So we need to list the crates manually, just like we list the functions manually.

I think something like below **should** work, but it **does not**.

```rust
macro_rules! call_all {
    (@funs $crat:ident $($fun:ident)+) => {{
        $($crat::$fun();)*
    }};
    ($($crat:ident)+ # $($fun:ident)+) => {{
        // error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
        $(call_all!(@funs $crat $($fun)*);)*
        //                       ^^^^^^ 
    }};
}

fn main() {
    call_all!(tokio rand # m_1 m_2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`seq-macro`](https://docs.rs/seq-macro/) crate to simplify that:

```rust
fn main() {
    seq_macro::seq!(day in 1..=25 {
        println!("Day {} Part 1: {}", day, d~day::part1());
        println!("Day {} Part 2: {}", day, d~day::part2());
    });
}
```

Sadly, it does not support formatting with leading zeroes (01, 02, ...) or using a variable for the number of days. The first could be fixed with a custom proc macro, the second could not.